# Passing array as prop to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-props

I have a component that I am trying with various props that I want to pass. One of which being an array (`tags`):

```
<RandomItem
    propOne="alphabet"
    propTwo="numbers"
    propThree="months"
    propFour="days"
    propFive="weeks"
    tags={["alpha", "bravo", "charlie"]}
/>
```

the structure for the `RandomItem` component is as such (I did not include other props beside `tags`):

```
export function RandomItem ({propOne, propTwo, propThree, propFour, propFive, tags}) {

    const tagSet = tags.map(tagItem => {
        return (
            <Tag tagName={tagItem}/>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div>
           {tagSet}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want to pass elements in the tags array to `RandomItem` but it keeps throwing an error as seen below. I have looked through the docs to work on different variations of the code above but still experience issues.

[image: error]

Below is the structure of `Tag` with a prop called `tagName` which is defined as such:

```
export function Tag ({tagName}) {
    return (
        <li className="randomTailwind">
            <div className="randomTailwind">
                {tagName}
            </div>
        </li>
    )
}
```

Ultimately, RandomItem is an element in another component.

Comment: Your code is working fine as I tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tags might be undefined.
Let's suppose you don't pass the `tagSet` property coz you forgot so it's undefined then you have to add a check for this case even if you don't forget.

```js
    const tagSet = tags && 
           tags.map(tagItem => <Tag key={tagItem} tagName={tagItem}/>)
```

Comment: It's short simpler answer.

Answer (score 0):

Created a simple codesandbox code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-hodgkin-xdfdpn?file=/src/App.js) . Check it out. It works fine, without any error. Let me know if there is anything else I can do for you.

**In the RandomItem when iterate over tagSet, provide a unique key for each item (in my example, I just provided name as key)**

```
const tagSet = tags.map((tagItem) => {
   return <Tag key={tagItem} tagName={tagItem} />;
});
```

Comment: That's clean and organized.

Answer (score 0):

You can map it directly to return like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Tag } from "./Tag";

export function RandomItem ({propOne, propTwo, propThree, propFour, propFive, tags}) {

    return (
        <>
        {
            tags.length > 0 ?
            tags.map((tagItem, i) => {
                return <Tag tagName={tagItem} key={i}/>
            }) : <li>No data available</li>
        }
        </>
    )
}
```